# Order of initialization with inherited and super classes

Tags: java, inheritance, initialization, declaration

*Question: Am I right that the `super()` constructor is called before the field initializations of my inherited class are done and by this the initializations can overwrite what I already initialized?*

The title and maybe the question sound somewhat confusing, so I will try to clarify my question.

I have an `abstract class Geometry` which has a `protected abstract void` method.
This method is called in the constructor of the Geometry. I figured out that this call caused the problem I had.

In my extended class, `ExtendedGeometry` I implemented the abstract method by calling a private method:

```
@Override
protected void createGeometry() {
    loadModel();
}
```

The `private void loadModel()` method filles a `vertexList` and is done.

The `vertexList` is defined as `private ArrayList<Integer> vertexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`.

When I now call `update()` on my model, the vertexList appears to be empty. And even before that, although I initialized the variable directly as shown above, it appears to be `null` in the `loadModel()` method.

So I think my steps are:

1. I call the (implicit) constructor of `ExtendedGeometry`.
2. I implicitly initialize a private member variable.
3. The super constructor calls my overriden method which calls `loadModel()`.
4. -> Odd: The member variable is now null, but declared!
5. I initialize the member variable again.
6. I fill it with values.
7. During the main loop I print the contents of the variable, but it's empty.

So in step 4 I expected the variable to be not null and in step 7 to be filled.

To solve it I found three solutions:

- The first solution is calling `loadModel()` in a constructor of my `ExtendedGeometry` instead of calling it from the overriden `createGeometry()`.
- The second solution is simply introducing an `init()` method for the `Geometry` class, which then calls the `createGeometry()`.
- The third solution is to simply only declare the member variable, but not initializing it.

So after trying out all this stuff I realized that the explanation seems to be that my superclass is able to work with the *declaration* but not the *initialization* of my subclass.
This leads me to the conclusions that the steps done are:

1. The declarations are promoted. (during compile time)
2. I call the (implicit) constructor of `ExtendedGeometry`.
3. The `super()` constructor is called.
4. The members of `ExtendedGeometry` get initialized. (What overrides the initialization done with `super()`.)

So my question is a simple yes/no question (which could be extended with explanations, if I'm wrong - or additions if I'm right):

**Am I right that the `super()` constructor is called before the field initializations of my inherited class are done and by this the initializations can overwrite what I already initialized?**

I first thought this is a problem of visibility, but while tracking down the problem this seems to be the only solution I can come up with.

Just for completeness and maybe to better understand here is my 95 % reduced code, sorry it has no JavaDoc. But I added some comments to show the problem and explain.

The most important one, here is the `ExtendedGeometry.java`:
    package geometry;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExtendedGeometry extends Geometry {
    // PROBLEM 1: the ArrayList is already initialized here
    private ArrayList<Integer> vertexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                     // usually this is Vector3f from lwjgl, but for
                     // STO I changed it to Integer

    private void loadModel() {
        // PROBLEM 2: but the ArrayList is null here!
        System.out.println("Initializing vertexList which is " + vertexList);

        // PROBLEM 3: leaving the following lines out
        //            does not change anything in the output
        //            of the update() method
        if(vertexList == null)
            vertexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // PROBLEM 4: filling the "newly" initialized vertexList, 
        //            but not the old one
        vertexList.add(1);
        vertexList.add(2);
        vertexList.add(3);
    }

    public void update() {
        // PROBLEM 5: as you can see, you see nothing: 
        //            the vertexList has no content
        System.out.println("vertexList of size: " + vertexList.size());
        for(Integer i : vertexList) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /*// PROBLEM 6 / SOLUTION: If I leave out the loadModel in 
      // createGeometry() but use this constructor instead
      // it works
    public SpecializedGeometry() {
        loadModel();
    }
    */

    @Override
    protected void createGeometry() {
        loadModel();
    }
}
```

The `Geometry.java` class, its super class:

```
package geometry;

public abstract class Geometry {
    public Geometry() {
        // every geometry has to be created
        createGeometry();
    }
    /*// If I add an init method like this, it works
    public void init() {
        createGeometry(); 
        // of course this line has to be removed
        // from the constructor
    }
    */

    // this is the abstract method to create a geometry
    protected abstract void createGeometry();
}
```

The `Simulation.java` just demonstrates how my program is build in general:

```
package simulation;

import geometry.ExtendedGeometry;

public class Simulation {
    private ExtendedGeometry geometry = null;

    public Simulation() {
    }

    public boolean init() {
        // initializes all simulation stuff, 
        // now only creates the geometry
        geometry  = new ExtendedGeometry();
//          geometry.init(); // this is a possible fix, see Geometry.java
        return true;
    }

    public void update() {
        // does calculations and updates everything
        // accordingly
        if(geometry != null) {
            geometry.update();
        }
    }
}
```

The `MainWindow.java`, nothing too special here:

```
package main;

import simulation.Simulation;

public class MainWindow {
    private Simulation simulation = null;

    public boolean init() {
        // create the simulation and initialize it
        // usually here is a bunch of initializations
        simulation = new Simulation();
        return simulation.init();
    }

    public void run() {
        // in this example I close after 10 loop runs, 
        // of course 1 would be sufficient as well
        int x = 0;

        // the main loop handles inputs, event manager,
        // updates, drawing, ...
        while(x++ < 10) {
            // update simulation
            simulation.update();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the boring `Main.java`:

```
package main;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        if(mw.init()) { // init and
            mw.run();   // run main loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have answered your own question that Yes, the extended class is fully initialized before the child class is initialized.

You have run into a basic rule of OOD, you should "never" call a non-static, non-final method from a constructor. If the constructor calls a method that can be overridden by a sub-class errors of this type are too common.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation, I never heard of that basic rule so far. I used it without noticing quite often because I saw and worked with the contructor + initializer principle. Very good to know!